# Trying to get raw id from an SQLite table where column name is given

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am trying to get this id from a table that has a column called "name". I tried various codes I found but I keep getting an empty cursor, which results in the exception:

```
CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0.
```

The last code I tried is

```
Cursor cursor =  db.rawQuery( "select * from " + TABLE_NAME + " where name='"+name+"'", null );
cursor.moveToFirst();
int countryId = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("id"));
```

I'd love to get some guidance. If some information is missing I'll provide it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First, use the recommended and safe way to supply the argument `name`, by using a `?` placeholder:

```
Cursor cursor =  db.rawQuery( "select * from " + TABLE_NAME + " where name=?", new String[] {name} );
```

Then use the result of the method `moveToFirst()` to check if the `Cursor` contains any row(s):

```
int countryId = -1;
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    countryId = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("id"));
}
```

Finally check the value of `countryId`.
A negative value means that the name was not found.
Of course this code will work if there are columns `id` and `name` in the table.